# extract specific column in UD corpus

Tags: python

I have a text file:

```
1 This D
2 is   V
3 one  A
4 example
5 .    P

1 This D
2 is   V
3 another 
4 example
```

I want to extract the 2nd column append to a list separated by newline `expected output: ["this is one example", "this is another example"]`

```
with open("data.txt","r") as f:
    print(f.read().split()[1])
```

But I get output `This` only. How can I do it?? get specific column (in this case sentences) in a UD corpus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f.read()` reads the whole file as a string.

```py
from itertools import groupby

with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

second_column = [line.split()[1] if line else "\n" for line in lines]

words_list = [list(group) for k, group in groupby(second_column, lambda x: x == "\n") if not k]

sentences = [" ".join(words) for words in words_list]
```

- `f.read().splitlines()` remove newlines and split lines into list.
- `groupby()` splits lists by `\n`.

Comment: I tried your code, it gives empty list. any idea why?

Comment: @Anna.balouch Did you mean `print(sentences)` give empty list? I have tested this code on your given data. Could you try to test it with your given data and see if it is still the same?

Answer (score 0):

You have to process all of the lines separately.

```
words = []
for line in open('data.txt'):
    words.append( line.split()[1] )
print( ' '.join(words) )
```

Comment: ```IndexError: list index out of range```, but when i do split('\n') it only gives first column i mean - This is one example. @TimRoberts

Comment: "List index out of range" means that the data does not all look like your example.  Are those line numbers part of the data?  Or did you add them just to confuse responders?

Comment: it is a big corpus, but looks like my example, not to confuse anyone. :) thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the file into separate blocks and then process them line by line:

```py
blocks = []

with open('data.txt') as f:
    blocks = [x.strip() for x in f.read().split('\n\n')]

sentences = []

for b in blocks:
    sentences.append(' '.join([x.split()[1].strip() for x in b.split('\n')]))

for s in sentences:
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
This is one example .
This is another example
```

Comment: but when I tried on my corpus it says ``` list index out of range ```